# Finding a more elegant regex solution

Tags: regex, deterministic

I have a question about a regular expression (I apologize in advance if there are mistakes in the terminology, my course isn't in English):

I wish to write a regular expression for all the strings that contain an even number of the substring 'ab', given that the letters are from the set `{a,b,c}`.

for example: `abab` `cbcabbcababcab` `cabcab` `baccbccabccabc` etc.

So far this is the shortest expression I came up with:
`(b+a*c+aa*bb*(a+cb*)*ab)*a*`

However, this seems a little convoluted, perhaps someone could suggest a shorter or more elegant expression? Thank you.

Comment: Does it have to be purely a regex or could you get the number of matches of "ab" and check if that number is even?

Comment: @AndrewMorton purely a regex

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessary more elegant but it doesn't rely on `c` & should work with any letters.  However, I'll leave that decision up to you, here's my solution:

```
^((?!ab).)*(ab((?!ab).)*ab((?!ab).)*)*$
```

[Here's an example on regexr!](http://regexr.com/3flen)